# how can i get single value at next page from multiple values in another page using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, php4

there are 3 JavaScript functions and each function contain a single table                  name in one page and i am calling any one function at single time.. how can i get that table name in another page using php ??

**page1.php**

```
session_start();                         
function one()
{
   $_session['one']='table1';
   window.location('page2.php');
}

function two()
{
   $_session['one']='table2';
   window.location('page2.php');
}
```

**page2.php**

```
session_start();
$tablename=$_session['one'];
```

i get only table2 value at next page when i call function one or function     two..how i get table1 value when i call function one and table2 value when i call function two ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to something like this.

```
    page1.php                         
     fuction one()
     {
       session_start();
       $_session['one']='table1';
       window.location('page2.php');
     }

     function two()
     {
      session_start();
      $_session['one']='table2';
      window.location('page2.php');
     }

     page2.php
     session_start();
     $tablename=$_session['one'];
```